# Move Text from Slider to New Line

Tags: flutter

I want to move this "Recent Transactions" to the next line.
For some reason, when I implement a slider, I want the "Recent Transactions" Text to move to the next line, It just does not, rather it stays on the same line as the slider.

My source code looks like this:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class BaseScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const BaseScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: SafeArea(
            child: SizedBox(
      width: double.infinity,
      height: 150,
      child: ListView(
        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
        children: [
          Container(
            margin: const EdgeInsets.all(15),
            width: 250,
            height: 100,
            color: Colors.green,
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            child: const Text(
              '\$5200.00',
              style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 15,
                  color: Colors.white,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            margin: const EdgeInsets.all(15),
            width: 250,
            height: 100,
            color: Colors.green,
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            child: const Text(
              '\$1200.00',
              style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 15,
                  color: Colors.white,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(height: 30),
          Text("Recent Transactions")
        ],
      ),
    )));
  }
}
```

This is what it Looks like

https://i.postimg.cc/y8CLqNxX/Screenshot-1664221289.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now you are adding the text "Recent Transactions" in the horizontal ListView.
Try wrapping the SizedBox with a Column and then add "Recent Transactions" as it's child

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class BaseScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const BaseScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
          child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start
        children: [
          SizedBox(
            width: double.infinity,
            height: 150,
            child: ListView(
              scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
              children: [
                Container(
                  margin: const EdgeInsets.all(15),
                  width: 250,
                  height: 100,
                  color: Colors.green,
                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                  child: const Text(
                    '\$5200.00',
                    style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 15,
                        color: Colors.white,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                  ),
                ),
                Container(
                  margin: const EdgeInsets.all(15),
                  width: 250,
                  height: 100,
                  color: Colors.green,
                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                  child: const Text(
                    '\$1200.00',
                    style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 15,
                        color: Colors.white,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(height: 30),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          Text("Recent Transactions",
           style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
          )
        ],
      ))
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: @Askay, thanks, that worked , how about moving it to the Left and making it Bold, could you pls edit. Just the Recent Transactions part...

Comment: Added to the edit in the answer above. Would appreciate if you accept the answer